# onclicklistener doesn't work on fragment - android studio

Tags: android

Greeting
When I click on TextView on the fragment, the app is crash. Please I need the expertise to help me to fix it. I have read many in the internet but no solution yet and I try many ways and all are not able to solve mine

```
package com.example.mymahine.nav1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.VelocityTrackerCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements onClickListener{
private TextView textView;
    public CameraFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
        TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_text);
        textview.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return view;


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

/*
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        TextView tv2 = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        tv2.setOnClickListener(new view2.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                }
             }
        );

    }
*/

}
```

Below is logcat:

06-01 13:14:28.607 4559-4559/com.example.mymachine.nav1 D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
06-01 13:14:28.608 4559-4559/com.example.mymachine.nav1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.mymachine.nav1, PID: 4559
                                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mymachine.nav1/com.example.mymachine.nav1.Main2Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
                                                                                  at com.example.mymachine.nav1.Main2Activity.onCreate(Main2Activity.java:17)
                                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
                                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618)
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)

fragment_camera.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.shakeralmoosa.nav1.CameraFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/frag_text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
    android:text="GO TO NEXT ACTIVITY"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: this is probably the problem, change to this textview.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Change  `textview.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener);` to         `textview.setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 2):

```
1    Replace your code with this:

    public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
    public CameraFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
    TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_text);
    textView.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
    public void onClick(View v){
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Comment: Paste your crash log this a simple task shouldn't be happening.

Comment: where can I find the crash log

Comment: If you are using Android studio for development then you'll find crash logs inside logcat view.
Go to tools bar then android inside that Android device monitor. open that inside you'll see logcat view. From there you can get your logs.

Comment: @user3315201 these are not application crash logs, clear all the logs just before starting your application and then paste your application crash logs.

Comment: I have cleared the cache and I rebuild the project. After I click on textview, the app stopped

Comment: @user3315201 what I meant in my previous comment was clear the logcat view just before clicking on the your text view and then share the new logs so that I can have a look where the problem is because this is a very simple one line code problem should be somewhere else

Comment: It's a nullPointer exception. Can you share your fragment_camera xml file. As I understand from your log android is not able to find out your textView inside that xml

Comment: I post it up @ sumit

Comment: Try removing private TextView textView; line just below
public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements onClickListener{

Comment: @user3315201 Can you please delete your code and paste my updated code in your fragment and let me know if app still crashes.

Comment: I have paste your code and I get an error said "cannot find symbol class Nullable"

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps,

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
        TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_text);
        textview.setOnClickListener(this);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        return view;


    }

      @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()){

     case R.id.frag_text :
         //your code...
         Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
         startActivity(intent);
     break;

    default:
        break;

     }

    }
```

Comment: @user3315201 try this

Comment: paste your crash log

Comment: where can I find the crash log

Comment: I meant your logcat what's showing there below your android studio there will be menu and click on Android monitor you will find the error paste it here

Comment: @user3315201 try to clear the cache and rebuild the project and then try my code it will work

Comment: I have cleared the cache and rebuild the project and app still crash when I click on textview in the fragment

Comment: then please paste your latest code where the app is crashing because the code  I posted is working perfectly on my phone

Answer (score 0):

check below code:

```
 public class CameraFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{
        private TextView textView;
        public CameraFragment() {
            // Required empty public constructor
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_camera, container, false);
            TextView textview = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.frag_text);
            textview.setOnClickListener(this);
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            return view;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Main2Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }


    }
```

Comment: implements onClickListener == implements View.OnClickListener ,      textview.setOnClickListener(this);

Comment: Register your Main2Activity activity to menifest file

Comment: I have already added it to manifest file
<activity android:name=".Main2Activity"></activity>

Answer (score 0):

You can set the click handler in xml(For your Textview) :

`android:onClick="onClick"
 android:clickable="true"`

In your Activity:

```
public class yourActivity extends Activity {

          public void onClick(View v) {
            ...
          }  
       }
```

Comment: It still the same.
When i click on the textview, app shows error "app has stopped"

Comment: Can tell me what error its showing in android monitor

Comment: I have added the logcat above in my question

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have resolved the problem

Last error was Nullpointer & can't activity started

I go to main2activity.java and do the followings:

1- remove

```
private TextView textview;
private View view;
```

change the following

```
textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

to

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

My app is working fine now.

Thanks for everybody who borrow me his time to help me.
See you in another problem.